# How do I evaluate a get_posts array with is_page?

Tags: pages, get-posts

How do I evaluate a condition in which specific pages in a `get_posts()` array are returned `true` by `is_page()`? Basically, I am trying to evaluate an array containing pages with a specific tag, so if the page is included in that list, show something.

From the docs, it seems I can use an array as an argument in `is_page()`, but the array returned from `get_posts()` doesn't work.

```
$top_level_pages = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'tag_slug__and' => 'Top Level'
    )
);

if (is_page($top_level_pages)) {
    //Show content for respective page
}
```

Comment: get_posts returns an array of post objects, is_page expects an array of page IDs, titles, or slugs.

Comment: @Milo Why can't I pull the titles from the object using `foreach ($top_level_pages as $top_level_page)`? then `$top_level_page -> name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wp_list_pluck` to extract an array of IDs from your query, then pass those to `is_page`.

```
$top_level_ids = wp_list_pluck( $top_level_pages, 'ID' );
if ( is_page( $top_level_ids ) ) {
    // do something
}
```